# OCaml open own module

Tags: build, module, ocaml

I want to `open Vegetables` in my `shoppinglist.ml` but I get an error message `Unbound module Vegetables`

My directory structure looks like this:

```
market/
|_ src/
   |_ shoppinglist.ml
   |_ shoppinglist.mli
|_ vegetables/
   |_ vegetables.ml
```

`shoppinglist.ml`:

```
open Vegetables
```

I use `dune build` and usually after that `dune utop .` to build my project.

`dune` in src:

```
(library
 (name shoppinglist)
 (libraries vegetables)
 (flags
  (:standard -warn-error -27)))
```

`dune` in vegetables:

```
(library
 (name vegetables)
 (modules vegetables)
 (flags
  (:standard -warn-error -27)))
```

I already tried many "solutions" but non of them worked out for me...

Comment: How do you build your project? You need to set up your build system so that `Vegetables` is included when building `ShoppingList`, but you're not showing us your build configuration, or even telling us which build system you use.

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot! I'll edit my post

Comment: You're still not showing us your build configuration. Where are the `dune` and `dune-project` files? And what's in them?

Comment: Sorry for being such a newbie! :(

Comment: Is that everything you need?

Comment: Do you also have a `dune-project` file in `market/`? If not, and you run `dune build` in `src/`, I believe it will use the current directory as the project root and won't be able to find the `vegetables` library.

Comment: I have but it just says `(lang dune 2.9)`

Comment: That's fine. I would expect it to work then, and I don't know what else to suggest. Uploading the whole project (or a [mcve]) to GitHub (or similar) might make it easier to reproduce and figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

With the following architecture I have no problem at all:

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── dune
│   └── main.ml
          let () = Shoppinglist.a ()
├── dune-project
├── program.opam
├── src
│   ├── dune
│   └── shoppinglist.ml
          let a () = Vegetables.a ()
└── vegetables
    ├── dune
    └── vegetables.ml
           let a () = Printf.printf "vegetables\n"
```

dune files are the same as yours, I just added a bin directory with a main.ml file to execute some code from the library.

The dune file in bin is:

```
(executable
 (name main)
 (public_name program)
 (libraries shoppinglist)
 (flags
  (:standard -warn-error -27)))
```

And

> ❯ dune exec program
>
> vegetables

So I'm not exactly sure what's your problem here.

Comment: Thank you for spending your time on it. I don't know why it doesn't work out for me either... I even reinstalled everything - nothing changed. Nevertheless thank you!

Comment: If you copy/paste exactly what I have, does it work? Did you try `dune exec program` or are you using `dune utop .` to test?